# What exactly does flask.abort() do?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, flask

I'm actually working with flask. 
I use flask in order to run a server, which will be requested by a chrome extension (js).

Requesting the server from the extension  is quite simple : I use the [chrome.runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) method. This method provides also a callback function, taking as parameters a JSON object (the response from the server).

E.g, suppose that I have this route on my server :

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
    def api_login():
        if 'username' not in request.json :
            return jsonify(success=false)
        else :
            return jsonify(success=true)
```

Then, I can in my extenstion, and more precisely in the callback function, check the success value :

```
function(response) {
    if(response.success){
        console.log("Login ok !")
    }
}
```

But now, my team doesn't want rely on this anymore, and wants to use http error code instead. I know that flask has an abort function, but while reading the documentation, I have had a lot of trouble to understand what it really does. When I call in my route :

```
else:
    abort(422, {"error":"Missing parameters"})
```

how can I use these information on the extension (js) ? Does flask automatically returns a specific JSON object when abort is called ? How can I check the error code ? I would like to do something like that in the client code :

```
if(response.status == 422) {
    console.log("Error")
}
```

One of the clues I have, reading all the StackOverflow threads about abort() is to define a specific error function using the decorator @app.errorhandler(code) :

```
@app.errorhandler(422)
def myErrorCase(error):
    return jsonify(status=422, error="missing parameters")
```

But I assume that there are more straightforward ways.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that i'm using JQuery for this example because it's easier and saves you from a lot of stress and cross-browser issues.

If you just pass in the error code like you're already doing, Werkzeug wraps the error message in html (Though you can still use regex to extract the error message on the client side, but that isn't really flexible). **So No Flask doesn't automatically return a JSON string back to the client**

The flask `abort` method either accepts an error code or it can accept a `Response` object. To achieve what you want to do, you have to pass a `Response` object to the `abort` method.

The Response Object is a wrapper around the [`werkzeug.wrappers.Response`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L1960) object

*There also a helper method to create a response object called [make_response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.make_response) so you don't have to fiddle with the `Response` class if you just want to create a simple `Response` object*

One of the reasons you'll create a `Response` object instead of allowing `render_template` or `abort` do it for you is when you need to add a custom header to a response or change the default headers that `abort` adds to the response.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, abort, render_template, Response
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('client.html')
    
@app.route('/resource')
def resource():
    error_message = dumps({'Message': 'You cannot see this!!!'})
    abort(Response(error_message, 401))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

client.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta content="">
    <style></style>
    
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <script>
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/resource',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                alert('Your request was successful');
            },
        
            statusCode: {
            401: function (response) {
                error = JSON.parse(response.responseText)
                alert(error.Message)
                
            }
            }
        });
    </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

You can handle different error codes by defining a corresponding function for them under `statusCode`

*You can still do this from pure Javascript, It just involves more keystrokes.*

You should really read through werkzeug's source code to get a better understanding on how `abort` and exceptions are generally handled. [This would be a good starting point](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py)

Comment: Ironically, the page you linked to to learn about exceptions is now 404'ing. I searched for "werkzeug exceptions.py" (it was in that url) and found a live page here: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py